# "Introduce yourself" section vs cover letter?

Tags: applications, cover-letter

I'm applying for a game programmer job online and they have a button where I can upload my resume file, and a section that says "Introduce yourself". I found it a bit weird cause usually all other sites I saw they ask for a cover letter.

I'm not 100% sure what to write. Should I give a brief intro about myself and still combine my cover letter or..?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would assume it's the first thing they read after your name.

I would also assume they get flooded with a lot of applications and that most of them are from people who are "grossly under qualified".

Your challenge is to **write a couple of sentences that suggest you are good at what you do and that you can benefit their team.**

Remember, the person reading this probably has another 50 or 100 to go through and is looking for an excuse to hit the 'delete' button.

You might want to also include a cover letter if it includes more narrative than fits in the introduction.  Just be darned sure you've written a custom letter for this application and that you make specific references to their company, the position, and how you'd be a fit.  No one likes to read "one size fits all" cover letters.

Comment: Thing is I do have a small "intro" section in my resume haha